# CSS Grid fill containers with same height, buttons on bottom

Tags: html, css, grid, tailwind-css

I have following sample, written in tailwind css:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/f9iOK1e0oM

I want to have my control buttons on the bottom if the grid containers, however, they have different content sizes for the blue "tag" boxes, so the grid gets increased in height by some containers. however, as I am working with grid, all boxes are getting this height then. this is ok. But my control buttons should be always on the bottom of the containers, so that "Enabled" and "Delete" should not be so far away from bottom for the second container.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `flex flex-col` to the `li` element. And `grow` to the first child div and `grow-0 max-h-max` to the second child div.

```
<li class="flex flex-col col-span-1 divide-y divide-gray-200 rounded-lg bg-white shadow">
    <div class=" grow flex w-full flex-col items-start justify-between p-6">
      <div class="flex w-full items-start justify-between space-x-3">
        <h3 class="truncate text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">243rfh83294d-23r8fj2n48r-24fi43bf</h3>
        <span class="inline-block flex-shrink-0 rounded-full bg-green-100 px-2 py-0.5 text-xs font-medium text-green-800"> running </span>
      </div>
      <p class="mt-1 whitespace-pre-wrap text-xs font-bold text-gray-500">Interval: <span class="font-normal">1234</span></p>
      <p class="mt-1 whitespace-pre-wrap text-xs font-bold text-gray-500">Next run: <span class="font-normal">1234</span></p>
      <p class="mt-1 whitespace-pre-wrap">
        <span class="inline-block flex-shrink-0 rounded-full bg-blue-100 px-2 py-0.5 text-xs text-blue-800">test 1</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="-mt-px flex shrink-0 grow-0 divide-x divide-gray-200 max-h-max">
        <div class="flex w-0 flex-1">
          <button class="relative -mr-px inline-flex w-0 flex-1 items-center justify-center rounded-bl-lg border border-transparent py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-500">
            <span class="ml-3">Enabled</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="-ml-px flex w-0 flex-1">
          <button class="group relative inline-flex w-0 flex-1 items-center justify-center rounded-br-lg border border-transparent py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transition hover:text-red-500">
            <span class="ml-3">Delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/ilTMM5glku

I have done this only for the second card, but you should do it for all cards. So that when the content changes, the button row will always stick to the bottom and keep the same height in all cards.

Hope this helps.